# Chrome Breaks Form by Persisting Drop Down List Selection on Back Button

Tags: c#, forms, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, back-button

Page A has a dropdownlist of shipping methods.

User makes a selection and clicks next.

Page B allows them to change their shipping address, which changes their shipping methods.

User clicks back button.

Page A shows new shipping methods in drop down, but Chrome has added a blank option at the top and made it the selected option.  This blank option DOES NOT EXIST in the view source.

Chrome is choosing to insert a phantom blank selection item when its persisted drop down list value no longer exists, rather than respecting the selected="selected" tagged option.

This causes .net event validation to fail whenever the user tries to interact with the form, because this blank selection isn't real. "Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled"

I've tried form.reset() on page load, and turning autocomplete off on the form tag.  Anyone have any ideas?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Does this problem occur with other browsers also?

Comment: No, the page works as intended in other browsers.  They select whichever option is selected="selected" tagged rather than inserting a blank option.  I should point out this is months old and I don't have the page in question any more - I had to go another route since I couldn't find a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Well I will try to find the solution and will tell you. Even you don't have that question but at least we can learn something new :)

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Chrome, I've been using .NET & Chrome with drop downs for a long time and not noticed this..?  I'd have a pick through your code with a fine toothed comb.  Maybe some Javascript is implemented on the page causing issues..?